# I want to add multipart data to server via AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have to add some data including image to server with following details:

Method: POST
Server URL: http://dev.aaaa.com/register

Headers: 
Key          Values
App_id       xxxxx
App_key      yyyyy
enctype      multipart/form-data

Body:

Key           value
data          {"code":"21187","fname":"Manish","lname":"Sharma"}
image         mypic.jpeg

Friends please help me to form request with body and headers under AFNetworking.

Thanks everyone for considering this problem and assisting me

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = //Your Image.

NSDictionary *params =@{@"data": @{@"code" : @"21187",
                                   @"fname" : @"Manish",
                                   @"lname" : @"lname"
                                  }
                        };


static AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *afPostManager = nil;

afPostManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.aaaa.com"]];
[afPostManager.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"]];

[afPostManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"xxxx" forHTTPHeaderField:@"app-id"];
[afPostManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"xxxx" forHTTPHeaderField:@"app-key"];
[afPostManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"enctype"];

afPostManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
                                    serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];


[afPostManager POST:@"register" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:title fileName:@"mypic.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success : %@",responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"failed : %@",error.localizedDescription);

}];
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but it didn't work. It encountered this error "2017-07-17 14:05:10.021 Implementation[1172:74340] failed : Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain".  Do I not require to add httpheaderfields like app_id, enctype etc

Comment: change application/json to  text/plain and try and you write that you want to send app_id and app_key in header thats why i added that if your api is not required that header then remove it

Comment: I tried this one also but it is producing same error. I did some modification also to suit its requirement but same problem..snapshot of postman....it will help you understand more  Link 1) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweySDAy0UNja1FscGJVVjIwSVE/view?usp=sharing    Link 2) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweySDAy0UNjNWZ6bnc3d0Rtc3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are sending all parameters in data so try this i had edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = <data to send>;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@“json = %@", jsonData);

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@“http://dev.aaaa.com/”];
NSLog(@“base URL = %@", baseURL);

AFHTTPSessionManager *sessionManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL sessionConfiguration:config];
[sessionManager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:500.0];
sessionManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
sessionManager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;

sessionManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [sessionManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

[sessionManager POST:@“register” parameters:dataDict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    //-------- here append images as form data -------------------------

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@“image” fileName:@“myimage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

} progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

    progressBlock(uploadProgress);

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

    successBlock(task, responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    faliureBlock(task, error);
}];
```

Use this may help you.

Comment: Hi Richard....There is no such method     [sessionManager POST:@"register" parameters:dataDict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> for......... and also in snap shot you can see I am not just passing data but an image alongside....